# In SvelteKit, is there a way to cancel a popstate event if user state isn't saved?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I have a component that allows a user to edit their state. This triggers a `notSaved` variable. I have a `beforeunload` event handler to handle reload and exiting the page to remind the user to save their state, but using SvelteKit, using the back button in the browser doesn't seem to trigger the `beforeunload` event. I also have a `popstate` event handler, because that is triggered when the back button is clicked, but I can't figure out how to prevent the `window.history` from changing if the `notSaved` variable is true.

Is there a way in SvelteKit to trigger a `Changes you made may not be saved.` popup similar to the one that is triggered on a `beforeunload` event when the back or forward button is pressed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`beforeNavigate`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-beforenavigate) function to be notified of a navigation intent in order to potentially block it, for example:

```html
<script>
    import { beforeNavigate } from '$app/navigation';

    let unsavedWork = false;
    let value = 0;

    beforeNavigate(({ from, to, cancel }) => {
        if (unsaved) {
            cancel();
            showUnsavedWorkPopup();
        }
    });

    function onChange() {
        ...
        unsavedWork = true;
    }

    async function save() {
        await ...
        unsavedWork = false;
    }
</script>

<input type="number" bind:value on:change={onChange}>
```

Comment: beforeNavigate/afterNavigate was added in version 227. If you're getting errors about not having a beforeNavigate function, look at your version and make sure you're not running an older version of SvelteKit.